# Dhtmlx Gantt chart: export to .pdf

Tags: pdf, export, dhtmlx

My task description is very long and when I'm exporting to .pdf the text is hide (I cannot make task column too much wide): how can I divide text into 2 or 3 lines inside the grid? Is it possible to force the text to new line?

Answer (score 1):

you can use DHX Gantt templates for grid columns https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__specifying_columns.html#settingthetemplateofdatapresentation

Then set and define a new class to the task text element. Something like this

```
gantt.config.columns = [
    {name:"wbs", label:"WBS", width:40, template:gantt.getWBSCode },
    {name:"text", label:"Task name", tree:true, width:170, template: function(task) {return "<div class='gantt_multiline'>" + task.text + "</div>"} },
    {name:"start_date", align: "center", width: 90},
    {name:"duration", align: "center" , width: 60},
    {name:"add", width:40}
];
```

Then define CSS for this class

```
<style type="text/css">
.gantt_multiline {
    white-space: normal;
    background-color: #FFE0F9;
    line-height: 110% !important;
    font-size:8pt !important;
}
```

I've put the BG color just to indicate the area we are working with.
Then. When exporting to PDF, you just need to send this CSS definition into the header
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__export.html#customstylefortheoutputfile

```
gantt.exportToPDF({
        name: "My Page.pdf",
        header: "<div><style type='text/css'>.gantt_multiline{white-space:normal;background-color:#FFF0F9;line-height:110% !important;font-size:8pt !important;}</style></div>"
    });
```

Also it's possible to set row height at DHX Gantt, for example
gantt.config.row_height = 40;

Here I found the live example of multiline at task's bars https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/snippet/213a0e27
Note that at this example the class is being applied only for large task names

Best regards!